# Non recursive way to list files

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following to recursively list files in a directory:

```
import os

def listdir(dir):
    items = [dir + '/' + item for item in os.listdir(dir)]
    for item in items:
        if not os.path.isdir(item):
            print (item)
        else:
            listdir(item)
```

As a sort of academic exercise I wanted to see how the above could be converted into a loop without recursion. What would be an example of doing that? So far I had something along the lines of:

```
def listdir(dir):
    while True:
        items = os.listdir(dir)
        for item in items:
            if not is.path.isdir(item):
                print (item)
            else:
                 # ?
```

Comment: @nbk There is a classic way using loops and "recursion" (in the sense of a function calling itself) by using some stack / queue, adding folders to it, then iterating overs the subfolders.

Comment: `os.path.isdir(item)` doesn't work for me, are you sure it shouldn't be `os.path.isdir(dir + '/' + item)`?

Comment: @xjcl yes that's correct, it was a typo.

Comment: @nbk that is absolutely false. All recursive functions can be mapped directly to a non-recursive implementation, you simply have to take care of the stack yourself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i posted an answer without recursive loop. as i wrote there i t possible and works, like my code, but you need more resources as you have to fill  alist

Comment: @nbk you don't need more resources, *the call stack requires memory*, here, you are explicitly maintaining the state instead of relying on the call stack.

Comment: in the accepted answer is Q which gets filled up and then removed one by one, since when it that no resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a FIFO queue (or equivalently, a deque):

```
def listdir(dir_initial):
    q = queue.Queue()
    q.put(dir_initial)

    while not q.empty():
        dir = q.get()
        items = os.listdir(dir)
        for item in items:
            item = dir + '/' + item
            if os.path.isdir(item):
                q.put(item)
            else:
                print(item)
```

If we encounter a directory we add it to the queue for later processing. If the queue is empty we know that we are done.

---

Note that this implements [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) as opposed to the recursive depth-first search, meaning you will get:

```
/a/
/b/
/a/1/
/a/2/
/b/9/
```

instead of

```
/a/
/a/1/
/a/2/
/b/
/b/9/
```

Comment: neat answer, thanks. Could you please add a couple lines on `Note that this implements a bread-first-search...`?

Comment: @David542 That means it will output all shorter paths before longer paths. I'll add a note

Comment: You should almost certainly be using a `collections.deque` here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, the `collections.deque` class is intended for this use case, while `queue.queue` is intended for synchronization between threads. So a `deque` would be slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a 'stack' of directories to list, and every time you encounter a new directory, add it to the stack. You could then loop while the stack is not empty over all directories:

Comment: right, would you want to show an example of implementing that?

Comment: Your implementation is better than mine was :)

Comment: I think your stack implementation is **FILO** by the way

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I think it's sorta a hybrid (maybe?) since the first directory in is the first one out, but after that it's filo.

Comment: @David542 Nope, it's just normal FILO. The very first directory added is both the first and last out since there is only a single one.

Comment: I think it would still be FILO - the first popped would still be the 'head' of the stack, it just so happens that there isn't anything else in it.

It's just a coincidence that it behaves like a FIFO when the size is one :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reconsidering, you can add the directiry to a list and process them

But your original code has some bugs and will not work

```
import os
def listdir(dir):
    dirstoprocess = []
    while True:
        items = os.listdir(dir)
        for item in items:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, item)):
                print (item)
            else:
                dirstoprocess.append(os.path.join(dir, item))
        
        if len(dirstoprocess) > 0:
            dir = dirstoprocess.pop(0)
        else:
            break
listdir("D:\mydi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a stack:

```
def listdir(dir):
    stack = [dir,]
    while stack:
        parent_dir = stack[-1]
        items = [parent_dir + '/' + item for item in os.listdir(stack.pop())]
        for item in items:
            if not os.path.isdir(item):
                print (item)
            else:
                stack.append(item)
```